# What impact do PHP sessions have on Magento functionality?

Tags: php, session, magento

My Magento store generates a whole lot of PHP sessions.  I run a cron job to trim them back after they get to be a few days old.

Questions is this: What is the impact on user experience of having their PHP session deleted?  Is there any?  I haven't discovered it...

Comment: Well, at a guess, it'll probably kill their basket for a start.

Comment: if you have "remember me" option it wont work when you delete session files

Answer (score 0):

Not really and as Jon Stirlng commented it will only terminate the session between the client and server. If user comes back new session is created. You can configure the session length from Magento admin

Comment: so user gets new session id with new empty basket

Comment: that is how sessions work yes , empty basket is however on application level not on server level like sessions are

Comment: just told obvious maybe someone don't know that :D